# how to make sum.toFixed handle commas with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to get my javascript to keep calculating the sum of columns after I insert in commas? When I try and insert a number for instance $5,000, it no longer will be able to calculate the sum? I'm quite new to Javascript and have only gotten this far by using code snippets form Stack Overflow. Please help me figure this one last part out. Thanks. Also, I'm using WordPress so that's why my "$" are jQuery. Thanks.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  //iterate through each textboxes and add keyup
  //handler to trigger sum event
  jQuery(".txt").each(function() {
    jQuery(this).keyup(function() {
      calculateSum();
    });
  });
});

function calculateSum() {
  var sum = 0;
  //iterate through each textboxes and add the values
  jQuery(".txt").each(function() {
    //add only if the value is number
    if (!isNaN(this.value) && this.value.length != 0) {
      sum += parseFloat(this.value);
    }
  });

  var sumQ = [];
  for (var i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
    sumQ[i] = 0;
    jQuery('td:nth-child(' + (i + 1) + ')').find(".txt").each(function() {
      if (!isNaN(this.value) && this.value.length != 0) {
        sumQ[i] += parseFloat(this.value);
      }
    });
    jQuery(".span7").find('input').eq(i - 1).val(sumQ[i].toFixed(2));
  }

  //.toFixed() method will roundoff the final sum to 2 decimal places
  jQuery("#sum").val(sum.toFixed(2));
}

var revenue = 12345678;
console.log(revenue.formatMoney()); // $12,345,678.00
```

```css
div.row-fluid.span7.form-inline {
  float: left;
}

.currencyinput {
  border: 1px inset #ccc;
}

.currencyinput input {
  border: 0;
}

.input-icon {
  position: relative;
}

.input-icon>i {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  transform: translate(0, -50%);
  top: 50%;
  pointer-events: none;
  width: 25px;
  text-align: center;
  font-style: normal;
}

.input-icon>input {
  padding-left: 25px;
  padding-right: 0;
}

.input-icon-right>i {
  right: 0;
}

.input-icon-right>input {
  padding-left: 0;
  padding-right: 25px;
  text-align: right;
}

table thead {
  background-color: #D3D3D3;
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 1.5;
  font-size: .8em;
}

thead td {
  padding: 5px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

table,
th,
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding-left: 10px;
  line-height: 1.5;
}

table tbody {
  font-size: .7em;
}

.dollars:before {
  content: "$";
}

td {
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <table class="table table-bordered">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Expense</th>
        <th>Total Program Expenses</th>
        <th>Amount Requested from LCEF</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tr>
      <td>Salary and Benefits</td>
      <td>
        <div class="input-icon">
          <i>$</i><input type="text" class="txt input-mini" placeholder="0.00" />
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="input-icon">
          <i>$</i><input type="text" class="txt input-mini" />
        </div>
      </td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Contract Services (consulting, professional, fundraising)</td>
      <td>
        <div class="input-icon">
          <i>$</i><input type="text" class="txt input-mini" />
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="input-icon">
          <i>$</i><input type="text" class="txt input-mini" />
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Occupancy (rent, utilities, maintenance)</td>
      <td>
        <div class="input-icon">
          <i>$</i><input type="text" class="txt input-mini" />
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="input-icon">
          <i>$</i><input type="text" class="txt input-mini" />
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Training & Professional Development</td>
      <td>
        <div class="input-icon">
          <i>$</i><input type="text" class="txt input-mini" />
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="input-icon">
          <i>$</i><input type="text" class="txt input-mini" />
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Insurance</td>
      <td>
        <div class="input-icon">
          <i>$</i><input type="text" class="txt input-mini" />
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="input-icon">
          <i>$</i><input type="text" class="txt input-mini" />
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Travel</td>
      <td>
        <div class="input-icon">
          <i>$</i><input type="text" class="txt input-mini" />
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="input-icon">
          <i>$</i><input type="text" class="txt input-mini" />
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Equipment</td>
      <td>
        <div class="input-icon">
          <i>$</i><input type="text" class="txt input-mini" />
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="input-icon">
          <i>$</i><input type="text" class="txt input-mini" />
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Supplies</td>
      <td>
        <div class="input-icon">
          <i>$</i><input type="text" class="txt input-mini" />
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="input-icon">
          <i>$</i><input type="text" class="txt input-mini" />
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Printing, Copying & Postage</td>
      <td>
        <div class="input-icon">
          <i>$</i><input type="text" class="txt input-mini" />
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="input-icon">
          <i>$</i><input type="text" class="txt input-mini" />
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Evaluation</td>
      <td>
        <div class="input-icon">
          <i>$</i><input type="text" class="txt input-mini" />
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="input-icon">
          <i>$</i><input type="text" class="txt input-mini" />
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Marketing</td>
      <td>
        <div class="input-icon">
          <i>$</i><input type="text" class="txt input-mini" />
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="input-icon">
          <i>$</i><input type="text" class="txt input-mini" />
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Conferences, Meetings, etc.</td>
      <td>
        <div class="input-icon">
          <i>$</i><input type="text" class="txt input-mini" />
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="input-icon">
          <i>$</i><input type="text" class="txt input-mini" />
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Administration</td>
      <td>
        <div class="input-icon">
          <i>$</i><input type="text" class="txt input-mini" />
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="input-icon">
          <i>$</i><input type="text" class="txt input-mini" />
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td contenteditable="true">Other - </td>
      <td>
        <div class="input-icon">
          <i>$</i><input type="text" class="txt input-mini" />
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="input-icon">
          <i>$</i><input type="text" class="txt input-mini" />
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td contenteditable="true">Other - </td>
      <td>
        <div class="input-icon">
          <i>$</i><input type="text" class="txt input-mini" />
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="input-icon">
          <i>$</i><input type="text" class="txt input-mini" />
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>

  </table>
  <div class="row-fluid">

    <div class="span7">
      <div class="form-inline">

        <table>
          <tr>
            <td>Quarters' Total</td>
            <td>
              <div class="input-icon">
                <i>$</i><input type="text" readonly="readonly" class="input-mini" />
              </div>
            </td>
            <td>
              <div class="input-icon">
                <i>$</i><input type="text" readonly="readonly" class="input-mini" />
              </div>
            </td>

          </tr>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It's simple, you just need to add `replace` function to remove all commas from the entire value using `this.value.replace(/,/g , "")`

Comment: Thanks. However, that didn't work, the sum is still not calculating when I add 5,000 value to any of the input fields.

Comment: Maybe I have to also add this replace content to the sum section of my javascript too?

Comment: Ok, is there any js error in console? because there are further calculation code in your function which can make issue. If you want to confirm that commas removed? you can use `console.log` to check like this `console.log(this.value.replace(/,/g , "") )`

Comment: or for simple solution you can change your input type to `number` instead of `text` like `input type="number"` so that input will not accept any character except numbers

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this issue by using input type as `number` instead of `text` so that it will prevent user's to add any commans or special characters except numbers like this:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  //iterate through each textboxes and add keyup
  //handler to trigger sum event
  jQuery(".txt").each(function() {
    jQuery(this).keyup(function() {
      calculateSum();
    });
  });
});

function calculateSum() {
  var sum = 0;
  //iterate through each textboxes and add the values
  jQuery(".txt").each(function() {
    //add only if the value is number
    if (!isNaN(this.value) && this.value.length != 0) {
      sum += parseFloat(this.value);
    }
  });

  var sumQ = [];
  for (var i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
    sumQ[i] = 0;
    jQuery('td:nth-child(' + (i + 1) + ')').find(".txt").each(function() {
      if (!isNaN(this.value) && this.value.length != 0) {
        sumQ[i] += parseFloat(this.value);
      }
    });
    jQuery(".span7").find('input').eq(i - 1).val(sumQ[i].toFixed(2));
  }

  //.toFixed() method will roundoff the final sum to 2 decimal places
  console.log('sum: ', sum);
  jQuery("#sum").val(sum.toFixed(2));
}

var revenue = 12345678;
console.log(revenue); // $12,345,678.00
```

```css
div.row-fluid.span7.form-inline {
  float: left;
}

.currencyinput {
  border: 1px inset #ccc;
}

.currencyinput input {
  border: 0;
}

.input-icon {
  position: relative;
}

.input-icon>i {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  transform: translate(0, -50%);
  top: 50%;
  pointer-events: none;
  width: 25px;
  text-align: center;
  font-style: normal;
}

.input-icon>input {
  padding-left: 25px;
  padding-right: 0;
}

.input-icon-right>i {
  right: 0;
}

.input-icon-right>input {
  padding-left: 0;
  padding-right: 25px;
  text-align: right;
}

table thead {
  background-color: #D3D3D3;
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 1.5;
  font-size: .8em;
}

thead td {
  padding: 5px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

table,
th,
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding-left: 10px;
  line-height: 1.5;
}

table tbody {
  font-size: .7em;
}

.dollars:before {
  content: "$";
}

td {
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <table class="table table-bordered">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Expense</th>
        <th>Total Program Expenses</th>
        <th>Amount Requested from LCEF</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tr>
      <td>Salary and Benefits</td>
      <td>
        <div class="input-icon">
          <i>$</i><input type="number" class="txt input-mini" placeholder="0.00" />
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="input-icon">
          <i>$</i><input type="number" class="txt input-mini" />
        </div>
      </td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Contract Services (consulting, professional, fundraising)</td>
      <td>
        <div class="input-icon">
          <i>$</i><input type="number" class="txt input-mini" />
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="input-icon">
          <i>$</i><input type="number" class="txt input-mini" />
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Occupancy (rent, utilities, maintenance)</td>
      <td>
        <div class="input-icon">
          <i>$</i><input type="number" class="txt input-mini" />
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="input-icon">
          <i>$</i><input type="number" class="txt input-mini" />
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Training & Professional Development</td>
      <td>
        <div class="input-icon">
          <i>$</i><input type="number" class="txt input-mini" />
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="input-icon">
          <i>$</i><input type="number" class="txt input-mini" />
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Insurance</td>
      <td>
        <div class="input-icon">
          <i>$</i><input type="number" class="txt input-mini" />
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="input-icon">
          <i>$</i><input type="number" class="txt input-mini" />
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Travel</td>
      <td>
        <div class="input-icon">
          <i>$</i><input type="number" class="txt input-mini" />
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="input-icon">
          <i>$</i><input type="number" class="txt input-mini" />
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Equipment</td>
      <td>
        <div class="input-icon">
          <i>$</i><input type="number" class="txt input-mini" />
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="input-icon">
          <i>$</i><input type="number" class="txt input-mini" />
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Supplies</td>
      <td>
        <div class="input-icon">
          <i>$</i><input type="number" class="txt input-mini" />
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="input-icon">
          <i>$</i><input type="number" class="txt input-mini" />
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Printing, Copying & Postage</td>
      <td>
        <div class="input-icon">
          <i>$</i><input type="number" class="txt input-mini" />
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="input-icon">
          <i>$</i><input type="number" class="txt input-mini" />
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Evaluation</td>
      <td>
        <div class="input-icon">
          <i>$</i><input type="number" class="txt input-mini" />
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="input-icon">
          <i>$</i><input type="number" class="txt input-mini" />
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Marketing</td>
      <td>
        <div class="input-icon">
          <i>$</i><input type="number" class="txt input-mini" />
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="input-icon">
          <i>$</i><input type="number" class="txt input-mini" />
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Conferences, Meetings, etc.</td>
      <td>
        <div class="input-icon">
          <i>$</i><input type="number" class="txt input-mini" />
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="input-icon">
          <i>$</i><input type="number" class="txt input-mini" />
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Administration</td>
      <td>
        <div class="input-icon">
          <i>$</i><input type="number" class="txt input-mini" />
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="input-icon">
          <i>$</i><input type="number" class="txt input-mini" />
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td contenteditable="true">Other - </td>
      <td>
        <div class="input-icon">
          <i>$</i><input type="number" class="txt input-mini" />
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="input-icon">
          <i>$</i><input type="number" class="txt input-mini" />
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td contenteditable="true">Other - </td>
      <td>
        <div class="input-icon">
          <i>$</i><input type="number" class="txt input-mini" />
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="input-icon">
          <i>$</i><input type="number" class="txt input-mini" />
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>

  </table>
  <div class="row-fluid">

    <div class="span7">
      <div class="form-inline">

        <table>
          <tr>
            <td>Quarters' Total</td>
            <td>
              <div class="input-icon">
                <i>$</i><input type="number" readonly="readonly" class="input-mini" />
              </div>
            </td>
            <td>
              <div class="input-icon">
                <i>$</i><input type="number" readonly="readonly" class="input-mini" />
              </div>
            </td>

          </tr>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```